# Cmake implicit link directory paths and how to set/override to enable building a common sandbox on different OS versions w.r.t lib dependencies

Tags: gcc, cmake, centos, dependencies, shared-libraries

I work with a large source tree that builds with cmake (rev 3.9.6). I often check the tree
out into a common NFS mounted path, and then build the sandbox on different machines (mounted
thru a common NFS path).

I would ideally like to be able to first build the tree on a CentOS7 system, and
then log into a CentOS8 system, type make from the top of the tree, and see
there is no need to reconfigure anything (cmake) or rebuild anything (all
make dependencies satisfied).

All the binaries built on the CentOS7 system run on the CentOS8 system and it looks
like all tests pass on both CentOS7 and CentOS8.  It also works to build the source tree
from scratch on a CentOS8 system as well (after dealing with how compiler warnings changed for
the newer compilers on CentOS8).

In practice I've found that building first on CentOS7 causes cmake generated files
(**build.make**) to end up with a CentOS7 gcc compiler specific path in them as a make dependency.
Or it looks to me like these generated cmake files from the CentOS7 build,

```
<top of tree>/CMakeFiles/3.9.6/{CMakeCCompiler.cmake,CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake}
```

set the serarch paths for the compiler and system libraries via,

```
set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5;/usr/lib64;/lib64;/usr/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5;/usr/lib64;/lib64;/usr/lib")
```

The first path, /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5, is unique to the compiler
version on CentOS7 and so does not exist on CentOS8.  A cmake generated dependency using this path (in **build.make** files)stops
make dead in its tracks when typing make at the top of the sandbox in NFS on a CentOS8 machine
because it can't resolve the non-existant path:

```
foo: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgomp.so
```

However, that pathname to libgomp.so thru the CentOS7 gcc path is a soft link,

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgomp.so -> ../../../../lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
```

Or the same version of libgomp.so (libgomp.so.1.0.0) will be referenced on **CentOS7** by:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgomp.so
/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1
```

Alternately, on **CentOS8** libgomp.so.1.0.0 is found via the paths:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libgomp.so
/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1
```

I've experimented with removing the gcc specific path from the implicit link cmake
variables to instead have,

```
set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/usr/lib64;/lib64;/usr/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/usr/lib64;/lib64;/usr/lib")
```

But the CentOS7 compiler specific path will still be found via the /usr/lib entry and I cannot exclude
/usr/lib as a search path altogether.  I would really just like to ***exclude* /usr/lib/gcc (?)** as an implicit search path
and even then I would have to specify linking against libgomp.so.1 or libgomp.so.1.0.0 instead of libgomp.so.

(BTW - I'm not sure setting those cmake variables explicitly before the project statement in the top level
CMakeLists.txt file worked, but I did not see any way to modify/change how the **CMakeC[XX]Compiler.cmake** files
are generated in the first place).

Now I could add a **custom command to trigger PRE_BUILD** on every cmake target to edit any cmake generated **build.make**
with that the dependency such that,

```
foo: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgomp.so
... edited thru custom command becomes...
foo: /lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
```

This does in fact work and allows make to finish checking (and find) all dependencies when I run it from the top
of the tree on CentOS7 or CentOS8 (after first building on CentOS7).   But I would prefer not to retroactively edit
cmake generated files.

So happy to hear any suggestions or if it's just unreasonable to expect to achieve this kind
of parity when building the same NFS mounted sandbox on two revs of the OS with different compiler (revisions and paths), i.e.,
the "right" thing to do is to always re-run cmake on CentOS8 and then rebuild everything on CentOS8.

Comment: A build tree, created by `cmake` invocation, is specific for the **machine**: It contains (in CMake-generated files) not only absolute paths pointed to the source tree and build tree, but also paths to the compiler, external libraries and include directories and so on. So creating build tree on CentOS7 and using it on CentOS8 - this is not how CMake is intended to be used. You need to create **separate build tree** on CentOS8.